# Создание наследников класса с отличием в лике единственной переменной

Tags: python, наследование

Нужно создать много однотипных классов, в которых де факто отличается единственная переменная класса.
Помню, что делал реализация под такой вот синтаксис создания класса: `class Token001(Token, "вот эта строчка в ту самую переменную"): pass`, но, хоть убейте, не могу вспомнить реализацию этого через конструктор экземпляра `__new__` или `__init_subclass__`. В основном попытки реализации через онные методы заканчиваются `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`. Туплю где то на ровном месте, но тут какие то горы :/

```
#class Token(object): ...

class Sign(object): #(Token):

    keyword = None

    def __init_subclass__(cls, keyword):

        cls.keyword = keyword

class Sign001(Sign, "sign 001"): pass
class Sign002(Sign, "sign 002"): pass
#...
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shamus_Rezol\Desktop\dwe.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Sign001(Sign, "sign 001"): pass
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Через `__new__` примерно тоже самое. Не понимаю, что не так то?

---

Да, можно вместо `pass` прописать `keyword = ..`, но мне не эта реализация интересна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позиционные аргументы используются для перечисления базовых классов, а ваш `keyword` должен быть именованным.

```
class Sign001(Sign, keyword="sign 001"): pass
```